# Throw an exception on partial sucess

Tags: apex, exception

Is it possible to throw an exception while performing a DML on a list of records, such that, successful records are committed to DB, but exception is thrown for the records which failed?
If I use Database class for DMLs with the allOrNone parameter set to false, successful records are getting commited, but no exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this :

```
for (Database.SaveResult sr :  this.someRecords) {
    if (sr.isSuccess()) {
        // Operation was successful
    }
    else {
        // Operation failed
        for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
            throw new CustomExceptionClass(err.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, won't the successful DMLs be rolled back?

Comment: Depends on which parameters you provide with Database.insert(), so yes. You could also have a boolean set up to check if even one record failed to save and then throw an exception

Comment: @d_k - throwing the error throws the error for the class no the individual record. Doing this will cause all records in scope to fail

Answer (score 1):

The system automatically rolls back a transaction if any exception makes it all the way up to the top of the call stack. You can't currently have any DML modifications survive an uncaught exception. I created [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l5BvAAI) as something I believe would be practical: the ability to do something in response to a failed transaction asynchronously when an exception is thrown (e.g. in your case, we could take the survivors, stuff them into an asynchronous transaction, then throw an exception).

Comment: As a workaround to log failures, I am iterating over the list of SaveResults, and for unsuccessful ones, instead of throwing an Exception, I am creating a new CustomException with the error details as the message, and sending that exception to my Exception Logging Utility class which saves the exception details in a Custom Object. I am yet to test this, but it should work.